# Send List Email Attachment Issue

Tags: email, list, bulk

my clients want a functionality to send bulk email with an attachment in jpg format, but in current scenario when I send an email the attachment is converted into .html link.

*please help*
if there is no solution then please mention

thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this setting in your org.

You can configure whenever you want to attach files as links or actual data in Setup > Email > Email Attachments.

From following options select last option to attach file as attachments.

- Always as links
- Include as attachment up to 3 MB or as links if more
- Include as attachment up to Salesforce email size limit or as links
  if more

It will be more easy to help if you will share the code. I hope you are using SingleEmailMessage method.